# ZeroMQ - Send from C# clrzmq - Receive C++ Message Empty

Tags: c#, c++, zeromq

I am having issues sending messages from a C# web service using clrzmq to C++ using ZeroMQ. I installed clrzmq with NuGet and I built libzmq from source for C++.

I have no issues sending and receiving to/from C++, however, every message send from C# to C++ arrives with zero size.

This is the C# code that does the PUSH.

```
var context = new ZMQ.Context(1);
var requester = Socket(ZMQ.SocketType.PUSH);
String connectionendpoint = "tcp://127.0.0.1:9997";
requester.Bind(connectionendpoint);

String testrequest = "TESTMESSAGE";
byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(testrequest);
SendStatus r = requester.Send(msg);
if (r == SendStatus.Sent)
{
       Console.WriteLine("Sent OK"); // <- Debugger arrives here with OK status
}
```

Output

```
Sent OK
```

This is the receiving end in C++

```
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t receiver(context, ZMQ_PULL);
int rc = zmq_connect(receiver, "tcp://127.0.0.1:9997");
std::cout << "Waiting for message " << std::endl;
zmq::message_t message;
bool success = receiver.recv(&message);
size_t msgsize = message.size();

std::cout << "Success " << success << std::endl;
std::cout << "Message Size " << msgsize << std::endl;
```

Output

```
Success 1
Message Size 0
```

I have also tried the following combinations of Connect/Bind from C# to C++:

- Bind - Connect
- Connect - Bind
- Connect - Connect
- Bind - Bind (fails, as expected. Both cannot bind to the same port)

---

**Q.** Is there something obvious I am missing/doing wrong?

**Q.** Why do both sender and receiver report successful transport with no errors when the message size is zero?

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: After looking at other questions similar to this, I checked the versions and the clrzmq libzmq.dll version is 4.1.5.0 and the C++ version I built from source is 4.2.1.0. I tried aligning these versions, but this had no effect.

Comment: Looks like the ZeroMQ project is no longer supported as questions are going unanswered on the mailing lists also. I don't know how to close questions, so I guess this comment will have to serve that purpose.

Comment: You should also try [github.com/ZeroMQ/clrzmq4](http://github.com/ZeroMQ/clrzmq4). This project is supported (2016-08). It is a C# binding to the C/C++ [ZeroMQ/libzmq](http://github.com/ZeroMQ/libzmq) project.

Comment: +metadings Thanks for your comment. In the end I decided that ZeroMQ is not production ready, so I implemented my own wrapper around Boost Asio for C++ and System.Net for C#. I will probably make it open source at some point in the future, but for now it does what I want.